# Accessing ga_sessions_* in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am trying to access Google Analytics data via the BigQuery API in App Script.
In my function I created the query:

```
  var projectId = 'bigqueryanalytics360';
  var query = "\
      SELECT * \
      FROM `bigqueryanalytics360.{dataset}.ga_sessions_*` AS ga_sessions \
      LIMIT 5 \
  "
  var request = {
    useLegacySql: false,
    query: query,
  }
```

however, when I make a request using this query, I get no data. On the other hand, when I specify a date `bigqueryanalytics360.{dataset}.ga_sessions_20211123`, I get the expected data.

I believe that the `*` is messing the query here, I think I need to escape it similarly to the way it's done in regex, but I am not sure how.

**How to run it on your own**

1. Access publically available dataset [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)
2. Create App Script
3. Create a file to access BigQuery data via API ([link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery)). Instead of this part:

```
var projectId = 'XXXXXXXX';

var request = {
    query: 'SELECT TOP(word, 300) AS word, COUNT(*) AS word_count ' +
      'FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;'
  };
```

Write as such:

```
var projectId = '{your-project-id}';
var query = "\
SELECT DISTINCT visitId \
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` \
LIMIT 10 \
"

var request = {
  useLegacySql: false,
  query: query,
  }
```

Make sure that you:

- Enabled BigQuery API ([link](https://docs.segmentstream.com/bigquery/enabling-bigquery-api))
- Enable Google API scopes ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330954/enable-google-api-oauth-scope))
- Enable BigQuery API via legacy editor (Use legacy editor >> Resources >> Advanced Google Services... >> BigQuery API)
  [image]

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What if there are many tables matching `*`?

Comment: @TheMaster that's the point with the `*` - it takes all of the tables that start with `ga_sessions_`

Comment: To answer your second question, I am not familiar with that myself neither. That was just my initial idea of going over it. :)

Comment: Well [it is valid syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#enclose_table_names_with_wildcards_in_backticks). Could you remove the `LIMIT` clause? Could you provide  the full script?

Comment: @TheMaster hmmm, but when I use `bigqueryanalytics360.{dataset}.ga_sessions_*`, I always get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and when I use the exact date `ga_sessions_20211123`, I don't get any errors

Comment: [Edit] to provide [mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster updated the question, let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Yes. Need the full script(Add the full script from documentation). Which line produces `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`?

Comment: @TheMaster I see now that the issue must have been the amount of data. I am using now `_table_suffix` (https://www.ga4bigquery.com/how-to-query-multiple-tables-with-table-suffix-ua/) to limit the data and it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#run_query) public documentation on the API that you are using, it’s recommended that you select every one of the tables that you want to use omitting the * that you are trying to use. This would bring the result without a problem, and you should add the fields that you want to retrieve from your query.

Comment: Nowhere in the link you provided is there any recommendation that each table should be queried specifically without the use of a wildcard. Could you provide another source for that recommendation?

Comment: Could you try and delete the limit clause from your query, I ran a query without it and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Within each dataset, a table is imported for each day of export. Daily tables have the format "ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD".

Ref: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

var query = "
SELECT * 
FROM `bigqueryanalytics360.{dataset}.ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD*` AS ga_sessions 
LIMIT 5 
"